# Deleting lines in a text file based on column length - Linux

Tags: linux

I have a large file containing lines such as below. Is there a sed or awk command in Unix I can used to delete each line where the length of the data in the second column is <60. In this example I would be left with just the first 3 line. 
I've tried unsuccessful so far.

```
Query1  1041  SVTQLTNDLFQTYLRKILS*MFKVIGCSDLLGNPLTLATN*IDGVLDLVQEPWSNS*KLS  862
Query1  1707  TTSNLTWLMQKNYMRQGILQFYKVIGSSDLLGNPIGLIDKLGSGVLEFFSEPYKGLLKPG  1767
Query1  2131  TIQTLSNLIIKNYVRQGILQFYKILGSSDILGNPIGLIDNLGTGVVEFFSEPYKGMLKPG  2191
Query1  1                                                 VFEFFNEPAKGLLKPK  17
```

Comment: second column meaning 1041, 1707, 2131 or 1? Are you checking its length or its value? Also, what did you try?

Comment: second column as in 0,1,2 the column with all the letters and *'s

Comment: It is still less clear what you want to do here. In your sample input, the 2nd column just contains numbers. Do you maybe mean the 3rd one? Please provide a more generic sample input together with the desired output.

Comment: The file is a long list of lines in the format above, I want to delete all lines where the length of the 3rd column is less than 60. Here I would like to get back.  Just the first three lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following AWK script would do.

```awk
/[0-9A-Za-z]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9A-Za-z*]{60,}+\s+[0-9]+/ { print($0); }
```

The regular expression matches the lines you want to keep. If a line is matched, it is printed out. You may have to tweak the regex to match your input format more precisely. I simply took what pattern I could infer from the few examples you've shown.

The regular expression explained:

- `[0-9A-Za-z]+` one or more alphanumeric characters
- `\s+` one or more spaces
- `[0-9]+` one or more digits
- `\s+` one or more spaces
- `[0-9A-Za-z*]{60,}+` sixty or more alphanumeric characters and asterisks
- `\s+` one or more spaces
- `[0-9]+` one or more digits

Another option would be to use

```awk
/./ { if (length($3) >= 60) print($0); }
```

which assumes that all lines are in the given column format. It matches any line and then conditionally prints it if the third column is wide enough.

In AWK, `$N` refers to the *N*-th column of the current line and `$0` to the entire line. By default, columns are split at white-space.

As [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) points out in a comment, the more terse syntax

```awk
length($3) >= 60
```

may be used to achieve the same effect as AWK's default behavior is to print the current line if the condition is true. I never happen to remember all the shortcuts one can take in AWK…

Comment: It is enough to say `awk 'length($3)>=60' file`: if this condition evaluates to True, `awk`'s default behaviour will do the rest: it print the current line whenever something is True.

Comment: yes that worked perfect!

Comment: @fedorqui Good point, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: The same applies to the `/regex/ {print ($0)}`. `/regex/` alone suffices.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for finding the dupe. I was pretty naive not to assume this has already been asked before. Do you think that I should delete my answer, given that the terse solution is already suggested in the dupe?

Comment: @5gon12eder no : ) It is a duplicate, but these are just other entry points to [SO], so -to me- it is completely fine to leave this solution here. I would just consider it cheating if you knew there was a duplicate, copied the solution from there and pasted here. Since your effort is big and clear to find a good solution, I think everyone benefits from having it here still.

Comment: @fedorqui Alright, I made it CW then.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane 'print unless 60 > length $F[2]' file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the `@F` array on whitespace